# Flickering phenomenon in pagination using React query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Every time we do internal pagination of the list, we patch data using React Query and distribute the resulting listData to the List component to turn it into a map.

```
  const { data: listData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["listData", { optionState: optionState }],
    queryFn: fetchData,
  });


      <List
        listData={listData}
        searchDataDeliver={searchDataDeliver}
        optionState={optionState}
      />
```

The problem is that when pagination is performed, a state without data is exposed to the UI until the React query receives data, causing a flickering phenomenon.

```
 const { data: listData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["listData", { optionState: optionState }],
    queryFn: fetchData,
    keepPrevious: true,
  });
```

I tried giving the keepPrevious: true option, but it doesn't help.